PDF.js in Vite library - Failed to fetch dynamically imported module
I have created a custom PDF viewer component in a Vue/Quasar Vite project, which is being built as a library. When using the library on local, everything works completely fine. However when deployed to production environment, I get the following error:
Setting up fake worker failed: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module


Following PDF.js docs, I am specifying the worker as such:
const workerUrl = new URL('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs', import.meta.url).href
PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = workerUrl;

I have also tried:
const workerUrl = new URL('../../../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs', import.meta.url).href


The files in the node_modules will be bundled by Vite, so don't use paths from node_modules.
Instead, you can use Explicit URL imports:
import workerUrl from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs?url'

// Also supports dynamic import:
// await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs?url')


Seems to also work on local but gets the same error in production environment.
